# How can I use Javascript "partial classes" with TypeScript style class definition

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, partial-classes

My application has an api wrapper class originally created by typing it out in TypeScript and copying/pasting the javascript into my app.

So the class def looks like this:

```
var SiteApi = (function () {
  function SiteApi(initially) 
  {
    //stuff
  }

  SiteApi.prototype.method1 = function(){/*stuff*/};
  SiteApi.prototype.method2 = function(){/*stuff*/};

  return SiteApi;
})();
```

Now when they are on the admin page, I want to add an additional admin.js file that will contain admin methods. For example

```
SiteApi.prototype.Admin.method1 = function(){/*stuff*/};
```

I found an example that does the "end result" that I want:

```
// file main
function SomeObject() {
    for (var i = 0, ii = SomeObject.Partial.length; i < ii; i++) {
         SomeObject.Partial[i].apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

SomeObject.Partial.SomeName = function() {
   ...
}

// file extra
SomeObject.Partial.SomeOtherName = function() {
   ...
}
```

(from: [Is it possible to give javascript partial class behavior like C# or monkey patching like Ruby does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998944/is-it-possible-to-give-javascript-partial-class-behavior-like-c-sharp-or-monkey))

However, the type of class definition they are using is different.

**How can I keep the TypeScript style class definition and yet do something similar to this example to add on the admin functions?**

For reference, we use our class like so:

```
siteApi = new SiteApi();
```

So I imagine there will also need to be a line of code tying the admin functions into it.

Note, I'm Ok with using something like `SiteApi.admin_method1` but the issue is that with TypeScript style classes the prototypes are defined in the definition and the object is executed, so it doesn't seem straightforward how to add in more prototypes later.

Comment: I see a vanilla constructor written in an _IIFE_. Is this what you're referring to when you say "TypeScript-style"? Also, is _Admin_ meant to introduce more to the prototype or just do more construction?

Comment: @PaulS. I've heard the TypeScript class style is kind of a mix of 2 different patterns, since it puts the prototypes in the middle, has a contructor named like the class, and "executes" the definition at the time of definition.  If this is IIFE, then yes.  Perhaps TypeScript complies to several forms depending on usage. But the above is exactly what we have, and it's TypeScript origin is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

Extend `SiteApi` but shadow the original, e.g. your *admin.js* loaded after would contain something like

```
SiteApi = (function (old_SiteApi) {
    function SiteApi() {
        old_SiteApi.apply(this, arguments);
        // further construction
        this.admin_method1 = function () {/* some admin instance method */};
    }
    SiteApi.prototype = Object.create(old_SiteApi.prototype);
    // add more prototype things
    SiteApi.prototype.admin_method2 = function () {/* admin stuff through prototype */},
    return SiteApi;
}(SiteApi));
```

### Option 2

Let `SiteApi` know to expect more stuff later, e.g. the original definition would become

```
var SiteApi = (function () {
    function SiteApi(initially) {
        //stuff
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < SiteApi.Extras.length; ++i) {
            SiteApi.Extras[i].apply(this);
        }
    }
    SiteApi.Extras = [];

    SiteApi.prototype.method1 = function () {/* stuff */};
    SiteApi.prototype.method2 = function () {/* stuff */};

    return SiteApi;
}());
```

Then the *admin.js* would do

```
SiteApi.Extras.push(
    function () {
        // stuff to make `this` into an Admin object
        this.admin_method1 = function () {/* some admin instance method */};
    }
);
```

### Option 3

The *prototype* of `SiteApi` is still exposed, if you don't need to do more construction and just need new methods you could simply add them in *admin.js*

```
Object.assign(SiteApi.prototype, {
    admin_method1: function () {/* admin stuff through prototype */},
    admin_method2: function () {/* more admin stuff through prototype */}
});
```

This last option is the only one which will effect instances of *SiteApi* created before *admin.js* was loaded.

Of course, you could mix options 2 and 3 together as well. Similarly, you could go with option 1 but call the new constructor a different name rather than shadowing the original, like *AdminApi*, and use that instead of *SiteApi* on the admin page.

Comment: If the Admin functions don't need construction, and the siteapi.js and admin.js are loaded asyncronously (and siteapi contrstruction does not depend on admin functions), what would be the best way to set up admin.js, so it will work even it it gets loaded first? :)   I can guarantee that api=new SiteApi() will not be called until both javascripts are loaded.  And by "work" I don't mean you can call admin functions before siteapi.js is loaded, but that they will end up in the SiteApi prototype

Comment: The code in _admin.js_ must be invoked after _siteapi.js_ if you want it to build upon _SiteApi_

Comment: I know, I was just wondering if there was a better way than setTimeout checking if the other one is there yet.