# Is it possible to communicate classes between files in JS?

Tags: javascript, class

I've been working on a website that requires a large amount of Javascript. Naturally, I have a number of classes and functions within my .js file. Is there any way, for the purpose of readability, to allow classes to be shared across multiple js files in the same directory?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking for [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to give javascript partial class behavior like C# or monkey patching like Ruby does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998944/is-it-possible-to-give-javascript-partial-class-behavior-like-c-sharp-or-monkey)

Comment: @MarceloGondim I don't see that as a duplicate. This question doesn't really have anything to do with partial classes.

Comment: @TylerRoper its the same behavior. in c# is called partial class... so we can share class across multiple files

Comment: @MarceloGondim I suppose OP could be asking about extending classes across multiple files, but as I understood it, it sounds like they just want to be able to define a function `MyFunction` or a class `MyClass` in `file_a.js` and use it in `file_b.js`. The question could fall into either the "duplicate" or the "needs clarity" bucket as it stands :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple files with the `export` and `import` commands

To make classes in a file accessible outside it, `export` the values:

```
// numberedClasses.js

class Class1 {
  constructor() {
    // Your code for the class here
  }
  // Your additional methods
}

class Class2 {
  constructor() {
    // Your code for the class here
  }
  // Your additional methods
}


export {Class1, Class2}
```

Next, you can access these using relative paths from another file (in this case I assume they are in the same directory)

```
// usingClasses.js

import {Class1, Class2} from './numberedClasses.js';

let itemC1 = new Class1();
let itemC2 = new Class2()
```